# Distributed training with Keras using multiple GPUs - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I try to run official example from https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/keras using distributed Keras on two nodes with one GPU each. I run `TF_CONFIG='{"cluster": {"worker": ["ip1:2222", "ip2:2222"]}, "task": {"index": 0, "type": "worker"}}' python3 test.py` on the first node and `TF_CONFIG='{"cluster": {"worker": ["ip1:2222", "ip2:2222"]}, "task": {"index": 1, "type": "worker"}}'` on the second one. Both of them detect GPUs when I print `device_lib.list_local_devices()` however I get the error shown below. When I run them separately without `TF_CONFIG` everything works properly. Any ideas what is wrong?

node1:

```
2019-11-13 18:20:00.974896: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1326] Created TensorFlow device (/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 7658 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, pci bus id: 0000:84:00.0, compute capability: 3.5)
2019-11-13 18:20:00.977161: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:250] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {0 -> localhost:2222, 1 -> ip2:2222}
2019-11-13 18:20:00.981865: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:365] Started server with target: grpc://localhost:2222
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

node2:

```
2019-11-13 18:20:04.121540: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1326] Created TensorFlow device (/job:worker/replica:0/task:1/device:GPU:0 with 7659 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, pci bus id: 0000:84:00.0, compute capability: 3.5)
2019-11-13 18:20:04.123868: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_channel.cc:250] Initialize GrpcChannelCache for job worker -> {0 -> ip1:2222, 1 -> localhost:2222}
2019-11-13 18:20:04.129259: I tensorflow/core/distributed_runtime/rpc/grpc_server_lib.cc:365] Started server with target: grpc://localhost:2222
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```